Hyper-Vにて仮想マシンを完全に削除したい
Hyper-Vにて状態が「開始中」にとどまっている仮想マシンがあります。
起動しても、「仮想マシン'Ubuntu2204'を起動しています...」と表示されるだけです。
完全に削除したいのですが、どのように行えばよいのでしょうか？

↓
解決しました。
参考サイト:
https://qiita.com/teracy/items/ce0c6e58e87e64867d13
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq vm*"
vmcompute殺す→vmms殺す
下記の画像が表示され、[削除]を押すと消えました。


この辺の記事を参考に必要な作業を抽出して行ってみては？ Microsoft Hyper-V マネージャー管理コンソールを使用しての仮想マシンの削除, Hyper-Vの仮想マシンを削除する, Hyper-V 仮想マシンの起動とシャットダウン手順, Hyper-V ゲストVMがフリーズしたときの強制終了

キャプチャ画像の右側に「サーバーの削除」がありますが、これは違うのでしょうか？

右上は 仮想マシンを提供している Hyper-V ホストの操作です。
リモートで管理する場合、複数のサーバ（ホスト）を接続できます。

解決に至った情報は質問に直接追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。

起動している仮想マシンを全て停止するコマンドです。
Get-VM | where {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | Stop-VM

PowerShell を「管理者として実行」してから入力してください。
参考）
Hyper-V と Windows PowerShell の使用 | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/try-hyper-v-powershell
Stop-VM (Hyper-V) | Microsoft Learn（英語）
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/stop-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps
追記）2024 10/9 14:11
仮想マシンを削除するコマンドです。
Remove-VM -Name "Ubuntu2204" -Force

参考）
Remove-VM (Hyper-V) | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/remove-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps
この Example 2 です。

Hyper-V マネージャーを使っているとして回答します。
仮想マシンを削除するには、状態がオフである必要があり、Ubuntu2204は開始中になっているため、削除できません。
Ubuntu2204を選択して、[操作]-[停止]として仮想マシンを停止してから、仮想マシンの削除を試してみてください。

Hyper-V マネージャーを使用しております。
[操作]ボタンを押下しましたが、[停止]ボタンが見当たりません。
コマンドプロンプトで仮想マシンを停止する方法がありますでしょうか？

仮想マシンを選択しましたか？ マウスで仮想マシンをクリックし、反転している状態で試してみてください

マウスで仮想マシン("Ubuntu2204")をクリック
↓
[操作]ボタンを押下するも、[接続] [設定] [ヘルプ]の3種類のみの表示だけです。

画像を追加しました。

仮想マシンで右クリックをしても同じですか？接続するとコンソールが表示されますか？表示された場合はそこで[操作]を押しても[停止]や[リセット]は表示されませんか？

仮想マシンで右クリックをしても同じです。
接続しても、「仮想マシン'Ubuntu2204'を起動しています...」と表示されるだけです。[操作]を押しても、[停止]や[リセット]はグレースケールのままです。
